# mysql server down after changing innodb_buffer_pool_size

Tags: mysql

I change my innodb_buffer_pool_size from 8M to 2G in my.ini. After that, I cannot connect to my SQL server.

[image]

My local server is down - when I try to log in using mysql -u root -p in window command., I get:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061).
```

I tried the following but still cannot restart my server:

1. Start the MySQL80 via windows service (start and shutdown)
2. Remove the ib_logfile (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, ib_buffer_pool, ib_data1
   from ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data

From my .err code (no idea why it is in my download folder while MySQL Server is installed in C drive):

```
2020-05-02T04:17:52.952456Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Users\ME\Downloads\mysql-8.0.19-winx64 (2)\mysql-8.0.19-winx64\bin\mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 5928
2020-05-02T04:17:53.320285Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011011] [Server] Failed to find valid data directory.
2020-05-02T04:17:53.352381Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-05-02T04:17:53.353424Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-05-02T04:17:53.357792Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Users\ME\Downloads\mysql-8.0.19-winx64 (2)\mysql-8.0.19-winx64\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Much appreciated for MySQL Guru's advices!

Comment: look into the error logs and see what is wrong.

Comment: One possible explanation (we are just guessing) is that there is an error on startup of MySQL and that it isn't actually starting. MySQL server writes a .err error log file, the default location is the mysql data directory. Review that for clues about any errors conditions when MySQL starts. Did we already try starting the MySQL server with a  working (known-good pre-change) my.ini file ?

Comment: Yes, I could start MySQL server before I changed the innodb_buffer_pool_size parameter.

Comment: @nbk I couldn't find any .err error log in "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data" or "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0" (no data folder for the latter)

Comment: then enable it in my.ini and there is probybly an error in the my.ini file, have you made a backup before changing anything.

Comment: Please see the error code from my edited question. 
Also, I didn't make any backup. I reinstall the MySQL server and made a copy of programData/MySQL server 8.0 folder. Changed the innodb_buffer_pool_size and had the same error. The error is still there even after I replaced the changed MySQL server 8.0 folder with the original copy.

Comment: @nbk any idea..?

Comment: you directory structure is not normal, but look for a my.ini there you find an option for zhe data directoiry  isusaly it lies under C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 and there si also the data directory, but mysql when it is installed correctly yould also be installed under programs and use programdata as folder because it has rights to write

Comment: I have both C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 and C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 after I install the MySQL server. But I only have my.ini and Data file for in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 but not in ProgrameFiles. Would this be an issue?

Comment: Also, when I said i changed innodb_buffer_pool_size, I actually did it in my.ini in ProgramData\MySQL Server 8.0